# jQuery template getting data back from target

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

iam talking abt this jquery-template

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

```
var data={/*json*/};

//complie template
jQuery.template('some_name', jQuery('#templateId').html());

//fill elm with id=target.
jQuery('#target').html(jQuery.tmpl('some_name', data));
```

My question is there any way to get data object back from target. Iam not looking for any strategies rather some inbuilt templating functionality.

Comment: This might help http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tmplItem functionality will do this for you: http://api.jquery.com/tmplitem/

you can do something like:

```
var myTmplItem = $("#target").tmplItem();
```

Then access it like:

```
myTmplItem.data
```